# How to change the color of a canvas tile when mouse is over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm trying to change the color of a tile when the user puts his mouse over it. Like whitening the tile. I'm using a tileset of 32x32 tiles. Here are the scripts.

**MAP.JS**

```
    function Map(nom) {
    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", '/maps/' + nom + '.json', false);
    xhr.send(null);
    if(xhr.readyState != 4 || (xhr.status != 200 && xhr.status != 0)) // Code == 0 en local
        throw new Error("Impossible de charger la carte nommée \"" + nom + "\" (code HTTP : " + xhr.status + ").");
    var mapJsonData = xhr.responseText;

    var mapData = JSON.parse(mapJsonData);
    this.tileset = new Tileset(mapData.tileset);
    this.terrain = mapData.terrain;
}

Map.prototype.getHauteur = function() {
    return this.terrain.length;
}
Map.prototype.getLargeur = function() {
    return this.terrain[0].length;
}

Map.prototype.dessinerMap = function(context) {
    for(var i = 0, l = this.terrain.length ; i < l ; i++) {
        var ligne = this.terrain[i];
        var y = i * 32;
        for(var j = 0, k = ligne.length ; j < k ; j++) {
            this.tileset.dessinerTile(ligne[j], context, j * 32, y);
        }
    }
}
```

**TILESET.JS**

```
function Tileset(url) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.referenceDuTileset = this;
    this.image.onload = function() {
        if(!this.complete) 
            throw new Error("Erreur de chargement du tileset nommé \"" + url + "\".");

        this.referenceDuTileset.largeur = this.width / 32;
    }
    this.image.src = "/tilesets/" + url;
}


Tileset.prototype.dessinerTile = function(numero, context, xDestination, yDestination) {
    var xSourceEnTiles = numero % this.largeur;
    if(xSourceEnTiles == 0) xSourceEnTiles = this.largeur;
    var ySourceEnTiles = Math.ceil(numero / this.largeur);

    var xSource = (xSourceEnTiles - 1) * 32;
    var ySource = (ySourceEnTiles - 1) * 32;

    context.drawImage(this.image, xSource, ySource, 32, 32, xDestination, yDestination, 32, 32);
}
```

**MAPDRAW.JS**

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var map = new Map(canvas.className);

window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width  = map.getLargeur() * 32;
    canvas.height = map.getHauteur() * 32;

    map.dessinerMap(ctx);

}
```

**PHP PAGE WITH THE CANVAS**

```
<canvas class="deuxieme" id="canvas"></canvas>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/excanvas.compiled.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/oXHR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/classes/Tileset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/classes/Map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mapdraw.js"></script>
```

If you also have the time, I would like to know if there is a way to know the number of the tile the user is having his mouse on. (For example, if that's the tile 3 (32x32 n°3), I want the tile to be black when the user point it, and white if that's another tile.

As for now, I just tried this:

```
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

    var rects = [
        {x: 0, y: 0, w: 32, h: 32},

    ], i = 0, r;

    // important: correct mouse position:
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    while(r = rects[i++]) {

        // add a single rect to path:
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, 32, 32);

        // check if we hover it, fill red, if not fill it blue
        if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fill();
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
    };
```

This is mostly taken from a tutorial, so it is not adapted at all to my code.
What I'm looking for now is a way to have the image back instead of the fill: blue and a way to target every tiles instead of having to write each tiles.

Answer (score 0):

There is this experimental technology `addHitRegion` that could help you, but unfortunately doesn't work in all browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion

If don't use it, then you need to compute the hits by yourself. First you will need to add an event listener for the mousemove in the canvas, and then you need to manually check the hit.

You will need to learn make the mouse event position relative to your canvas (try to search for mouse position relative to element).

After that, you will need to do the computations by yourself. if you have, lets say, a rectangle with top, left, width and height, to see if a point (x, y) is inside it, you need to check:

```
if (x >= left && x < left + width && y >= top && y < top + height) {
   // hit
}
```